# Smarty foreach properties not working

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I am trying to use various smarty foreach properties like last, first, total but nothing seems to work. Although the looping is correctly working. Below is my code:

```
{foreach from=$myArray key=icon item=myValues name=myValueArray}  
  {if $myValueArray.first} first element {/if}  
    {$myValues["data"]}  
{/foreach}
```

I thought it must be simple so I used link [smarty doc](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl) and SO question but nothing exactly discuss this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the doc: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

```
    {foreach} loops also have their own variables that handle properties. 
    These are accessed with: {$smarty.foreach.name.property} with “name” being 
    the name attribute.

    Note
    The name attribute is only required when you want to access a {foreach} property, unlike {section}. Accessing a {foreach} property with name undefined does not throw an error, but leads to unpredictable results instead.


    {foreach} properties are index, iteration, first, last, show, total.
```

so:

```
{foreach from=$myArray key=icon item=myValues name=myValueArray}
// {if $myValueArray.first} first element {/if}
{if $smarty.foreach.myValueArray.first} first element {/if}
{$myValues["data"]}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `{if $smarty.foreach.myValueArray.first}`. There is [example 7.12](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.first)